# C++ 11 conversion error

Tags: templates, c++11

I am trying to call the template for a `int` vector but I did not found a way to solve the following error (I have looked over the suggested questions on the site):

```
D:\CodeBlocks\Tests\Templates\main.cpp|51|error: conversion from 'std::vector<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<int>' requested|
```

Bellow it's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

template<typename C> C f(C x)
{
    return x;
}

template <class A, class B> typename std::vector<B> my_map(A fct,B v)
{
    int n = v.size();
    std::vector<B> r(n);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        r[i]=(B) fct(v[i]);
    }
    return r;
}
int main()
{
   std::vector<int> mapvector {1,2,5,7,9};

   std::vector<int> ret = my_map(&f<int>,mapvector);

   std::copy(ret.begin(), ret.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: it should presumably be `std::vector<B> my_map(A fct,const std::vector<B>& v)`

Comment: and that `typename` is redundant, if not even entirely wrong

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki it works now with `const` and with or without `typename` I thought it was something wrong with the function call or the return... You can post your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

template<typename C> C f(C x)
{
    return x;
}

//template <class A, class B> typename std::vector<B> my_map(A fct,B v) <-- before
template <class A, class B> typename std::vector<B> my_map(A fct,const std::vector<B>& v)
{
    int n = v.size();
    std::vector<B> r(n);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        r[i]=(B) fct(v[i]);
    }
    return r;
}
int main()
{
   std::vector<int> mapvector {1,2,5,7,9};

   std::vector<int> ret = my_map(&f<int>,mapvector);

   std::copy(ret.begin(), ret.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout));

   return 0;
}
```